# Deferring Tax on Social Security payments

Tags: united-states, income-tax, social-security

Recently, I went to a free seminar (sales pitch) on retirement income. The speaker claimed that he has a method where you can defer the income tax on your Social Security payments to age 85. However, he refused to tell us how to do it unless we came in for a one on one session.

Is there a way to defer taxes on Social Security payments?

I am in the United States.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[An AARP document](https://www.aarp.org/retirement/social-security/info-2023/reduce-taxes-on-benefits.html) suggests considering:

- Prioritize withdrawals from tax-free retirement accounts.
- Donate your RMDs to charity.
- Take IRA or 401(k) withdrawals before claiming Social Security.
- Make tax-deductible contributions to retirement accounts
- Defer gig-work income.
- Offset investment gains with losses
- Pivot to a tax-efficient investment portfolio.

I suspect one or more of these is the secret ingredient in this character's snake oil.

Comment: I suspect you are on the right track. What  you are really telling me is that once I start taking Social Security benefits, I need to pay tax on them.  So the answer to my question is no.

Comment: I may be wrong, but that's my best guess. "I have a secret financial strategy" rarely turns out well.

Comment: @keshlam _Especially_ when it's "I have a secret to avoid federal income taxes." Those 'secrets' usually fall into one of two camps: things that are relatively well-known and things that may get you arrested.

Comment: Note that even if one could defer taxes somehow, unless you can predict your finances, and tax laws, far into the future it is extremely unclear that this would actually benefit you significantly.